# By Creating an API to get the HTML body from a webpage, will be webpage visits increase?

Tags: html, api, mobile, google-analytics

if we are creating an API from a wordpress website to get the content in the HTML body in a webpage, and using the Same API to display content on the mobile apps, will the views or visits on the website increase?

Answer (score 1):

Standard integration for GA is via Javascript, so as long as your scraper does not execute Javascript pageviews and visits will not increase. That covers visits from your script.

However if you output the resulting HTML to a webview in a mobile app visits might increase if the tracking code is included in the HTML body (standard GA is implemented in the head, but if for example the code is implemented via the Google Tag Manager that's usually within the body).

So there's no clear yes/no answer and you should err on the save side and have your api remove known tracking scripts.

Your question is tagged Google Analytics specifically, note that other systems might use simple image tags for tracking; with those systems pageview will increase if you copy the HTML body of the page.